# Как исправить ошибку Не удалось найти указанный пакет SDK "Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator" C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sdk

Нужно было в свою отдельную ветку добавить изменения из основной. Я сделал `git pull origin main`, после чего нужно было решить несколько конфликтов. Я выбирал все варианты из ветки `main`. Но в итоге, после решения конфликтов, у файла `.csproj` написано `load failed` и вывелась ошибка:

```
[MSB4236] не удалось найти указанный пакет SDK "Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator". C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props at (14:38)
```

С чем это может быть связано и как это можно исправить?

Если переустановить проект и открыть мою или любую другую ветку, такой ошибки нет. Она появляется только после слиния веток.

Answer (score 0):

Был дот нет 6, скачал 7, а потом опять 6 и всё заработало. Но насколько это верное решение не знаю